# "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'" - when trying autocomplete

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete, error-handling, devuan

Whenever I start typing in a command which uses `$(  )` expansion, and I press tab while typing in the inner command, I get an error:

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
```

Thus, for example, I might see:

```
$ echo $(echo hbash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

on my terminal. Where is bash encountering the error? How can I determine which file?

Notes:

- I've recently installed a new (and incompatible) distribution but have kept my home directory, so some settings/files are bound be messed up.
- In case it helps, I'm now on Devuan Ascii.

Comment: Why not start trying to modify / remove bash related config files from your home directory like `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`?